# Use a managed SES IP pool in Terraform by default

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-ses

I'd like to configure Terraform with a default SES configuration set that sends through an AWS managed IP pool. So far I have this:

```
resource "aws_sesv2_dedicated_ip_pool" "this" {
  pool_name = "default-app"
  scaling_mode = "MANAGED"
}

resource "aws_ses_configuration_set" "this" {
  name = "default-app"
}
```

I don't see how to set this as the default or how to associate the two in Terraform.

Comment: Could it be you need a different resource: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/sesv2_configuration_set#delivery_options?

Comment: I couldn't find that for some reason. Good find! I'll give it a go.

Comment: @MarkoE That fixed my issue with the resources, but I still don't see how to associate the configuration set with an identity.

Comment: Under `delivery_options` block there is the `sending_pool_name` argument.

Answer (score -1):

Replace "your_region" with the AWS region you are working in.
Ensure you have a valid SNS (Simple Notification Service) topic ARN and replace "your_sns_topic_arn" with the actual ARN.
This configuration not only sets up the dedicated IP pool and configuration set but also includes an example of an SES event destination (SNS topic) for capturing various email-related events. Adjust the configuration based on your specific requirements and environment